# Connect to drone and take off

Tags: android, sdk

The SDK(and apk) is pushed to the phone using Android Studio. The app(phone) connects to the drone over the wifi network created by the drone. And everything is connected properly. But when the flight controller tries to turn on the motors or take off there is an undefined error.

```
flightController.turnOnMotors(djiError -> {
            if (djiError == null) {
                flightController.startTakeoff(takeOffDjiError -> {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Taking off");
                    FlightControllerState flightControllerState = flightController.getState();
                    Log.i(TAG, "" + ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(flightControllerState));
                    if (takeOffDjiError != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error taking off : " + takeOffDjiError);
                        Thread.dumpStack();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I have tried with the mobile remote controller, and there is no result, i.e. the motors do not engage.

I expect the motors to react to the changing input data for the flight controller.

Comment: Well, I purposely removed the propeller blades because I didn't want the machine wandering off somewhere. It turns out that the hardware doesn't like that at all and is extremely stubborn about being 'complete'. Putting the propellers back on the machine and violla, machine crashing everywhere, as is expected.

Answer (score 0):

See comment above.

Left here for historical reference.

## DJI #Drone #Mavic